# Why storage account deployment with same name is taking time in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I created a storage account, then deleted the resource group. Then created another resource group with a different name, and created the storage account with same name. The deployment is going on for 10 minutes.

Update: It took 15 minutes.

Comment: Is the storage account being deployed as "Classic" or "Resource Manager"?

Comment: In my experience it normally takes this much time to deploy a storage account under Resource Manager mode. I am also curious to know the reason behind it.

Comment: Is your storage account location the nearest to your region?

Comment: Yes @juvchan it is in east asia. Note that if I use a different name, it creates the storage account very quickly, within 2 minutes.

Comment: Is this behavior consistently reproducible?

Comment: I can also reproduce the issue. Maybe Azure is, behind the scene, formatting or zeroing the storage space...

Answer (score 0):

Recreating a storage account with the same name as a recently deleted account can take longer if your account has a lot of data. If it is just an empty account, the experience should be the same.

We will need additional information such as your storage account name and date/time that you experienced the delay to investigate further. If you want us to look deeper into this, please email us the additional information to ascl@microsoft.com.

Thanks,
Aung

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, but my storage account being deleted/recreated is empty. Are you sure storage content has an impact on that time?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem. Have been waiting 30 minutes now.